# Kernel density estimation of AR(1)

Tags: prediction, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

I recently started playing around with estimation joint densities with Matlab using its mvksdensity function and at the moment I am fooling around with an autoregressive process of order 1 (AR(1)) given by $X_{n} = 0.9 X_{n-1} + w_n$, which $w_n$ being gaussian white noise of unit variance. I am attempting to predict the AR(1) by estimating the conditonal expectation $ E(X_n|X_n-1) $ using the estimated joint density. If I set the joint density's dimension to the dimension of the model (which would be two, i.e. $f(X_{n-1},X_n))$, I get results which nicely align with what is expected, i.e. the expected value predictor achieves the maximum of the prediction gain $PG := 10 \cdot \text{log}_{10}(\frac{\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_e^2})$, where $\sigma_x^2$ is the variance of the AR(1) process and $\sigma_e^2$ is the variance of the prediction error $e(n) := x(n) - \hat{E}(X_n|X_n-1)$, where the $\hat{}$ denotes the estimate. Now I wanted to see how the estimation behaves, when I keep the very same AR(1) process, but increase the model order to three, i.e. I now assume a density $f(X_{n-2}, X_{n-1}, X_n)$ and again try to estimate the conditional expectation $E(X_n|X_{n-1}, X_{n-2}$.
I calculate the conditional mean from the conditional density by first estimating $f(X_{n-2}, X_{n-1}, X_n)$ and $f(X_{n-2}, X_{n-1})$ and calculating from these estimates the conditional density $f(X_n | X_{n-1}, X_{n-2}) := \frac{f(X_{n-2}, X_{n-1}, X_n)}{f(X_{n-2}, X_{n-1})}$. Using this estimate, I numerically integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \hat{f}(x | X_{n-1}, X_{n-2})  dx \equiv \hat{E}(X_n|X_{n-1}, X_{n-2} )$. Playing around with the bandwidth I achieved reasonable results.

Now my actual question arises:
I am sweeping through some bandwidths at the moment and noticed that my prediction gain now surpasses, albeit only by alittle of 0.4 dB or 5 %, the theoretical maximum, i.e.  $PG_{EXP} > 10\cdot \text{log}_{10}(\frac{\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_e^2}) = 10\cdot \text{log}_{10}(\sigma_x^2)$, the latter equality following from unit variance of the excitation noise $w_n$. $PG_{EXP}$ is the prediction gain of the conditional expected value predictor.

Is it possible for this approach to overfit? What could be the reason for this phenomenon? The pseudorandomness? To speed up my calculations, I estimated the joint density on 10k samples, but predict and evaluate the performance only on the first 1k, this never gave me trouble with a linear predictor. I assumed so far, that either one is estimating correctly the joint densities and then can achieve the maximum prediction gain, or the estimate is incorrect resulting in a deviation from the true conditional expectation resulting in lower prediction gain than the maximum.